# how to redirect the whole yii app to point it to a subdirectory located outside the protected folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

the structure was like this

```
htdocs
     somefiles
     myfolder/image
             /js
             index.html
             style.css
     protected
             /models
             /controllers
             /blahblabha

index.php
.htaccess
```

i want to redirect this whole app, to point to the myfolder
so that what ever URL I typed in the browser, it will get redirected to the
index.html of the myfolder directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this in your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myfolder%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myfolder%{REQUEST_URI} -d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfolder/$1 [L]
```

To display non-existing URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myfolder%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/myfolder%{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myfolder/ [L]
```

Comment: there's also another problem , when I type www.currentdomain.com/blahblah...and this blahblah, does not exist in the directory, it says page not found in server..i want every attempted url whether they exist or not that are typed prior to the main domain..should all be redirected to the subfolder that I pointed at in my first post..how ?

Comment: so what i mean is that..if i type let's say for example, www.currentdomain.com/blahblah ...it will display the content of the myfolder

Comment: I removed the previous one you've suggested and tried the edited one....i got an Internal Server error, any other ideas ?